# If error handling ASP.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, webforms

how to display a message and stop the remaining codes from running.

eg.

```
if (num == -1){

    message.Text = "wrong";

} 

int happy == 0;

if (happy != 0)
{

    message.Text = "wrong";

}
```

if num is =-1 it should show the message and not execute the remaining codes.

how do i do that?

p.s. this is just a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put a `return` there and the code will stop.

```
if (num == -1){

message.Text = "wrong";
return;
}

int happy == 0;

if (happy != 0) {

message.Text = "wrong";
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
message.Text = string.Empty;
int happy == 0;
if (num == -1){
    message.Text = "wrong";
}
else if (happy != 0) {
    message.Text = "wrong";
}

if(message.Text == "")
{
 // Remaining code
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
if (num == -1){
    message.Text = "wrong";
    return;
}
if (happy != 0) {
    message.Text = "wrong";
    return;
}
// Remaining code below this will only execute if num != -1 or happy == 0
```